# JavaScript Restrict User From Clicking Button Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-events

I am trying to restrict the user from clicking on a button multiple times. They can click on the button once when the page loads. If the page is reloaded the same should apply the user can click on the button only once.

I am using the following code however it doesn't seem to work for me

```
$("#doAccess").click(function() {
   $("#doAccess").removeAttr('onclick');
   DoSave();
});
```

Comment: I'm unclear on this, so do you want them to be able to reload the page and click again or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the button after it's been clicked

```
var accessBtn = $('#doAccess');

accessBtn.click(function() {
   accessBtn[0].disabled = true;
   DoSave();
});
```

Comment: Would it be more performant to use this rather than $("#doAccess") again? Also curious, why are you grabbing the first element in an array? Interested to know what I'm missing in this example. Thanks!

Comment: It's because the jQuery selector returns the results in an array of DOM elements. In this case, because you're using an ID you know there's only one element targeted so it's safe to grab the first element in the array - which references the DOM element. Performance-wise you're right it's better to not use the selector twice, so you can make use of the `this` reference. You can also cache it to another variable, if you're going to be referencing to that dom element anywhere else in your code.

Comment: Cool, do you have to use the array element when selecting on an ID? I believe as a convenience because you know it's only selecting one, jQuery doesn't require you to use the array selection.

This is where I was curious about using this rather than the selector in your callback, so you wouldn't have to select either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you really need is:

```
$("#doAccess").one('click', DoSave);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PxvBG/)**

[.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) - Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
$("#doAccess").once('click', function() {
    DoSave();
});
```

You should probably also gray out or disable #doAccess, whatever it is.